# Bind To Appointment for Updating using Exchange Web Services

Tags: vb.net, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, appointment

I am writing a synchronisation service within VB .NET to synchronise other user's calendars into a user's mailbox.  I am hitting a problem though with binding to an appointment to update it, basically I get a message advising that access is denied?  Although I can read the calendar I am updating and I can create new entries in the same calendar.  I would be grateful if anybody could suggest what is going wrong and how to resolve it as far as I know I am correctly binding as I used MSDN notes on the method to write my code:

```
DestExchServer.ImpersonatedUserId = New ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.PrincipalName, sDestinationUser)
sCurrentID = nlTempNode("id").InnerText

' **The error happens on the line below:**
appAppointment = Appointment.Bind(DestExchServer, New ItemId(sCurrentID))**

' Update the event bound to
appAppointment.Subject = nlTempNode("subject").InnerText
appAppointment.Location = nlTempNode("location").InnerText
appAppointment.Start = nlTempNode("startDateTime").InnerText
appAppointment.End = nlTempNode("endDateTime").InnerText
appAppointment.IsAllDayEvent = nlTempNode("allDayEvent").InnerText
appAppointment.Body = nlTempNode("body").InnerText
appAppointment.Sensitivity = nlTempNode("sensitivty").InnerText
appAppointment.Importance = nlTempNode("importance").InnerText
appAppointment.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite)
appAppointment = Nothing
```

Comment: Could you try to reduce your code snippet to just enough to show the issue?! I had to read through a lot of code that's not directly related to the problem.

Comment: OK, done that, as you can see before I attempt to bind to the appointment I have used impersonation, but the code still fails at  **appAppointment = Appointment.Bind(DestExchServer, New ItemId(sCurrentID))** with a access is denied?  Yet pretty much the same method to create an appointment rather then update works fine (the code under the line If iFoundDestinationAppointment = 0).

Comment: Does this happen for *all* appointments? Or only for those appointments that were created by a different organizer than the owner of the calendar?

Comment: As the organizer is not passed from the source appointment to the destination appointment (yet) the organizer for all of the appointments created in the synchronized copy of the calendar is the person I am impersonating.

Comment: Is there a more exact error message than "Access Denied" and an exception type?

Comment: Can you see what the EWS editor says?  https://ewseditor.codeplex.com/ It's invaluable when debugging apps like these.

Comment: A first chance exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponseException' occurred in Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll - {"Access is denied. Check credentials and try again."} .  I will take a look at the ewseditor it might identify where I am going wrong.  Thanks.

Comment: @GaryHall did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Sorry, no, we found another way of achieving the same objective, I run a script daily that gives members of a AD user group Reviewer Access to the calendars we require other members of staff to have access to, this allows the group members to see the selected users Calendars.  When they wish to perform the same on an iPhone we use an app called 'TeamCal' (which was why I was trying to develop this method as at the time I could not find a iPhone app to allow a user to view other users Calendars.